# How to install PowerShell 3.0 or 4.0 via WSUS

Tags: windows, powershell, wsus

I can't seem to find any information about Windows Management Framework 4.0 on WSUS.
As far as I can tell it's not available for approval or download in WSUS, and it looks like Windows Management Framework 3.0 has [been revoked](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8cd493fb-d320-45ca-8bf0-bacdf4eadbcd/windows-management-framework-30-on-wsus?forum=winserverwsus).

Failing these two methods, is there any way to install PowerShell 4.0 or even 3.0 en-mass via WSUS?

Answer (score 2):

The only WSUS-driven solution I can think of would be to use the [Local Update Publisher](http://localupdatepubl.sourceforge.net/) utilities to [extract and deploy](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/localupdatepubl/index.php?title=Distributing_Hotfixes_and_MSUs_with_LUP) the [still available KB patch](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2506143) that installs WMF 3.0.